# discover the devices connected to the computer via command line?

Tags: networking, discovery

I would like to look at all the devices in my network . I would like to do it using the command line .

Is it possible , Please give me directions  the name of the tool that would help achieve the purpose .

Comment: What is your environment? What Operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to elaborate on what you mean by 'look' and 'network'. A network could be anything. Do you mean devices on the same subnet as yours? Probably on the same Ethernet cable?

There are scanners that can scan your subnet and spew out a list of IP addresses that respond to an ICMP echo (Ping).

You could take a look at 'nmap' too if you want to get additional information about these devices.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post that on:
superuser.com
StackOverflow is more geared toward programming, whereas superuser is more geared toward questions such as 'What commandline tool can I use to do xxx?'

Answer (score 0):

There are two common tools, available for linux, windows and other platform.

1. nmap
2. snmp

For the second, you can try  to send a snmpget to your local broadcast address, community *public* and oid *SysName* or *SysDescr*.